# return all equal columns

Tags: python, pandas

if I have these dataframes

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'index': [1,2,3,4],
                    'col1': ['a','b','c','d'],
                   'col2': ['h','e','l','p'],
                   'col3': ['p','l','i','z']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'index': [1,2,3,4],
                    'col1': ['a','e','f','d'],
                   'col2': ['h','e','l','p'],
                   'col3': ['p','l','i','z']})
```

df1

```
   index col1 col2 col3
0      1    a    h    p
1      2    b    e    l
2      3    c    l    i
3      4    d    p    z
```

df2

```
   index col1 col2 col3
0      1    a    h    p
1      2    e    e    l
2      3    f    l    i
3      4    d    p    z
```

i can run `df1['col1'].equals(df2['col1'])` on each column, but if they're so many columns i'll need a code to return all equal columns or all unique columns, how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible compare this way if same number of rows and same index in both `DataFrame`s - compare by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and test if all `True`s columns by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html), last select by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df11 = df1.set_index('index')
df22 = df2.set_index('index')

df = df11.loc[:, df11.eq(df22).all()]
print (df)
      col2 col3
index          
1        h    p
2        e    l
3        l    i
4        p    z
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df11.eq(df22))
        col1  col2  col3
index                   
1       True  True  True
2      False  True  True
3      False  True  True
4       True  True  True
```

For not matched columns filter columns names with inverted mask by `~`:

```
cols = df11.columns[~df11.eq(df22).all()]
```

Comment: That's awesome, but is it possible to get a list of unique columns out of this?

Comment: @A.RahmanMahmoud - Do you think `cols = df11.columns[df11.eq(df22).all()]` ?

Comment: Nope, these are the equal columns I meant the unique ones, the not equal columns, and thanks a lot really

Comment: @A.RahmanMahmoud - I am sorry, do you think unique values, it means here are in data all unique columns? Or unique columns names? Waht should be returned for ` unique ones` ?

Comment: i mean to get a list every column name except the output of `df11.columns[df11.eq(df22).all()]`, in this example it should return `col1`

Comment: @A.RahmanMahmoud - I got you, use `df11.columns[~df11.eq(df22).all()]`

Comment: Perfect, you're a life saver

Comment: sorry but can I use the same `df11.columns[~df11.eq(df22).all()]` but with `equals` instead of `eq`? since `eq` marks identical columns with NaNs as unique columns.

Comment: @A.RahmanMahmoud - There is used `~` it means not equal, so it select all columns which `False` if test `df11.eq(df22).all()`

Comment: when i run `df2020.Old_CompanyName.equals(df2019.Old_CompanyName)`
 i get `True`, but when i run `df2020['Old_CompanyName'].eq(df2019['Old_CompanyName']).all()` i get `False`, `['Old_CompanyName']` is a column with mixed `NaN` values and real values, and it's identical in both data frames, that's why i'm trying to use `equals` instead

Comment: @A.RahmanMahmoud - You can use `df = df11.loc[:, df11.fillna(1)).eq(df22.fillna(1)).all()]`

Comment: @A.RahmanMahmoud - You can replace missing values to same values like `1` in both DataFrames for matching.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which works even if the names of the columns are different in df1 and df2 (I added an underscore to column names in df2 to show that).
It loops over df2 columns and uses a dict (`dict_tuple_to_name_1`) to look up efficiently for equal columns in df1.
The order of columns in both dataframes does not matter, neither the index.
It outputs (in `dict_equal_cols`) the  the list of columns in df2 equal to each column in df1.
I added another column col4 in df2 so that col3 and col4 in df2 are both equal to col3 in df1 (to test the case of multiple columns in df2 equal to a given column in df1).

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'index': [1,2,3,4],
                    'col1': ['a','b','c','d'],
                   'col2': ['h','e','l','p'],
                   'col3': ['p','l','i','z']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'index_': [1,2,3,4],
                    'col1_': ['a','e','f','d'],
                   'col2_': ['h','e','l','p'],
                   'col3_': ['p','l','i','z'],
                   'col4_': ['p','l','i','z']})

dict_tuple_to_name_1 = {tuple(df1[col_name]): col_name for col_name in df1.columns}
dict_equal_cols = defaultdict(list)

for col_name_2 in df2.columns:
    col_name_1 = dict_tuple_to_name_1.get(tuple(df2[col_name_2]))
    if col_name_1 is not None:
        # we found equal columns, so we add the column name to the list
        dict_equal_cols[col_name_1].append(col_name_2)

for col_name_1, col_names_2 in dict_equal_cols.items():
    print("column {} in df1 has these equal columns in df2 : {}".format(col_name_1, col_names_2))
```

Which outputs :

```
column index in df1 has these equal columns in df2 : ['index_']
column col2 in df1 has these equal columns in df2 : ['col2_']
column col3 in df1 has these equal columns in df2 : ['col3_', 'col4_']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using merge on transposed dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'index': [1,2,3,4],
                    'col1': ['a','b','c','d'],
                   'col2': ['h','e','l','p'],
                   'col3': ['p','l','i','z']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'index': [1,2,3,4],
                    'col1': ['a','e','f','d'],
                   'col2': ['h','e','l','p'],
                   'col3': ['p','l','i','z']})

df1t = df1.T
df1t['col_name'] = df1.columns
df2t = df2.T
df2t['col_name'] = df2.columns
df_match = pd.merge(df1t, df2t, how='outer', indicator=True)
df_match


0   1   2   3   col_name    _merge
0   1   2   3   4   index   both
1   a   b   c   d   col1    left_only
2   h   e   l   p   col2    both
3   p   l   i   z   col3    both
4   a   e   f   d   col1    right_only
```